# How to read specific columns in CSV file java

Tags: java, csv, readfile

my CSV file looks like this:

```
Id;date;code;type;category;name;position;formula
10;;;2010-02-01;;000010;P;W;NormalDays;10;#formelTest
55;;;2050-05-02;;000055;D;C;SpecificDays;55;#formelTest2
60;;;2301-08-03;;000060;A;C;NotNormalDays;60;#formelBlablblabla
75;;;2012-01-08;;000075;P;W;VulgaryDays;75;@formellbalbalbalbababa
```

I would like to read from it lines by line only from only first column **id** and last column **formula**. How can I do this? Thanks for help.

The code:

```
File file = new File("Filename.csv");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (String line : lines)
   { 
     String[] array = line.split(",");
     System.out.println(array[0]);
   }
```

Comment: Do you have a sample code of what have you do?

Comment: File file = new File("Filename.csv");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(),
StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (String line : lines) {
       String[] array = line.split(",");
       System.out.println(array[0]);
        }

Comment: Simple read file. I dont have idea how can I read specific columns...

Comment: It would  be better to edit your question and add the code, for StackOverflow question guidelines

Comment: Why do you do a split with ',' if you use ';'?

Comment: And why are you creating an array of lines inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing your code:

```
File file = new File("Filename.csv"); 
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
for (String line : lines) { 
   String[] array = line.split(";"); 
   System.out.println(array[0]+" "+array[array.length-1]); 
}
```

You will notice that I changed the comma to a semi-colon as the split separator and added a bit to the `println`, which will be the last item in your split array.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String filename = "matches.csv";
    File  file = new File(filename);
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String data = sc.next();
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```